# Unexplained `capturing self strongly` warning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I have a number of methods in blocks, firing one inside the next, in order to sync some data with a web service. Most of these behave completely fine, but one method won't let me mention `self` after it's been called, giving me a `capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle` warning.

Here's what I mean:

```
[self deleteEntriesCorrespondingToDeletedNotesInNotebook:notebook success:^{
    [self deleteNotesToMatchDeletedEntriesWithCompletion:^{
       [self deleteResourcesToMatchDeletedMediaItemsWithCompletion:^{
           [self addOrUpdateEntriesCorrespondingToUpdatedNotesInNotebook:notebook success:^{
               //Anything calling a property or self after this point is a problem and gives the warning
               [self addOrUpdateNotesCorrespondingToUpdatedEntriesWithCompletion:^{

               }];
           }failure:^{

           }];
       }];
   }];
}failure:^{

}];
```

Any ideas why only items passed this point have a problem with this? If I replace the method before it with another similar method, there isn't a problem. The problem is only existent after `addOrUpdateEntriesCorrespondingToUpdatedNotesInNotebook:` is used.

Comment: Could you also add the internal implementations of each method?

Comment: Google "Objective-C blocks weak self", this is a dupe of lot of identical questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556605/capturing-self-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a-retain-cycle)

Comment: and of [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)

Comment: I know the ways to patch over the problem, using weak references, but I want to actually stop it from happening, since it doesn't happen with any other method.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the question is **not** why this code generates a retain cycle, but why does `addOrUpdateEntries...` cause  that warning, but `deleteEntries...` causes no warning. - I tried to answer that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15536473/1187415.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clang - Blocks retain cycle from naming convention?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535899/clang-blocks-retain-cycle-from-naming-convention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* of your methods could "behave fine" or create a retain cycle, depending on what they
do with the completion block.

As explained here: [Blocks retain cycle from naming convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535899/clang-blocks-retain-cycle-from-naming-convention), the clang compiler uses naming conventions to decide whether to emit
a warning or not: All methods `add...` and `set...` (but not `addOperationWithBlock`!) 
cause a warning, other methods don't.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self deleteEntriesCorrespondingToDeletedNotesInNotebook:notebook success:^{
    [self deleteNotesToMatchDeletedEntriesWithCompletion:^{  //this line here and the rest in your downward loop
```

dont use self. Instead do this before the first line

`__typeof__(self) __weak _weakSelf = self;`
and then from second line onwards, replace `self` with `weakSelf`

try this. cheers